# Configuring Submodules for GitHub and Gerrit public repo Integration

Tags: git-submodules, gerrit

I have a public GitHub repository with a corresponding clone in my Gerrit server. Now, I want to add a new subproject to it, which will also be a public GitHub repository with a corresponding clone in Gerrit. However, I'll only be pushing changes to Gerrit. I want that when I clone from Gerrit, my submodule should also point to Gerrit, and the commits of my public GitHub parent repository should point to my GitHub subproject repository. How can I achieve this setup effectively?